# Android Application named after film

Tags: copyright

I was wondering if you are able to call an Android Application after a name of a film. I have tried researching online and have found information regarding character names and graphics etc but couldn't find anything about the names of films. I am not planning on using any graphics or sounds from the film simply just the title. I have created the application myself and am planning on putting it on the Play Store soon with both a free and paid version being available. I was thinking as I will be earning money from it maybe it then does become an issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The basic underlying idea is that whatever you use should not give targeted audience an idea that your product has something to do with movie because of the same title or the app belongs to movie production house.

Since it is an android app & you are using a film's title, there should be very less chances that any prospective infringement or passing off can take place because whatever app does has no remote connection with the film or its contents, characters etc. The end purpose, contents and targeted audience of both are entirely different.

Answer (score 0):

Film titles practically always get trademarked. You can [search for registered word-marks at the US Patent and Trademark Office](http://tess2.uspto.gov/).

Trademarks usually only apply to specific product categories, so when you are lucky they didn't register it for software. But unless you are dealing with a very small independent production company which couldn't afford to do it, you can expect that they registered the trademark for everything with the slightest commercial potential.

Comment: I have just updated my question with an image of the results I got back. So does that mean as long as its not called one of these then I'm fine for example "Dude Where's My Hat".